# Upload directory with no prefix (://) was not found for file uploads

Tags: media, 9

I am not able to get file uploads of any type to work on my Drupal instance when I attempt to add media using the built in form. When I upload an image file, I get:

[image]

And looking at the log messages in Drupal I see:

`The upload directory ://2022-05 for the file field field_media_image_private could not be created or is not accessible. A newly uploaded file could not be saved in this directory as a consequence, and the upload was canceled.`

I do not understand where the path :// comes from. I would have expected it to be something like public:// or private:// but not just ://.

A few things I tried with no success (for test purposes):

- Setting relative instead of absolute paths for files and private folders in settings.php.
- Setting 777 permissions on the files and private folders.
- Disabling every module except core and rebuilding all caches.

What else could be the source of this issue? What else can I check?

Comment: It's supposed to be public:// or private. Some module somewhere has  a bug. You'll need to track down which module.

Comment: Have you defined `$settings['file_public_path']` value in settings.php

Comment: @miststudent2011 I did, it's just set to 'files'

Comment: @Jaypan I uninstalled every single module except core and this issue still happens.

Comment: Try setting it as `$settings['file_public_path'] = 'sites/default/files';`

Comment: @miststudent2011 I tried that but it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

In your question you said you made sure the private directory is relative and not absolute. The private files directory must be specified as absolute. Below is the documentation for `file_private_path`, from `default.settings.php` (emphasis, mine).

> A local file system path where private files will be stored. This
> directory *must be absolute*, outside of the Drupal installation
> directory and not accessible over the web.

Comment: I just meant that this is something I tried, based on other answers on this website to similar issues. I originally had it set to an absolute path. Neither absolute nor relative works in my case unfortunately.